# Scheduling Jenkins pipeline to run at an interval of morethan 31 days

Tags: jenkins, triggers, cron

I am working on a Jenkins pipeline and I wish to have it run after every 85day at around 9 am. I have the below snippet in my Jenkins pipeline, but i'm not so sure whether it is correct or not given that 85 is above the maximum number of days in a month:

```
triggers {
  cron 'H 9 */85 * *'
}
```

Can someone help me please!